# "rain was coming till tomorrow"

Tags: past-tense, future, progressive-aspect, will-be-going

I am asking this question on behalf of a friend of mine. Do tell me, can and when or why can we use past form when we predict something in the future. I agree the phrase is not full. Anyway, the friend said that she heard it on the radio and it was the weather forecast. She was a little surprised by the past form. Unfortunately, she could not remember any sentence before or after.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of that is if there was a *not* in there.  `The weatherman said the rain was *not* coming till tomorrow.`

Comment: I think your friend must have heard wrong. If you report a weather forecast to someone else, you might just say: "She said that rain was coming tomorrow." But I seriously doubt that any weather forecaster would utter the words: "Rain was coming till tomorrow".

Comment: Or maybe: "She said that rain was continuing till tomorrow."

Comment: I would understand the forecaster to be meaning two things: 1) Rain is coming now. 2)Once it starts, the rain will continue till tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe the sentence was : He would have bought an umbrella if he knew the rain was coming till tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is that you don't use a past construction to talk about the future.  We talk about the future using will, going to, present continuous, or present simple.

The only guess I can make for what your friend heard is that she heard reported speech, and the 'is coming' became 'was coming' because of the back-shifting of the verb when we report. Could she have heard something like "The forecast said no rain was coming till tomorrow"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your friend reported the radio announcement correctly, and assuming that the announcer was not mistaken, then the announcer was not speaking [Standard English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_English) but some English dialect or pidgin.

In Standard English neither the [simple past](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html), [past continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) nor [future in past](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html) are used to denote a future event or possibility of future event. However, in languages that do not have tripartite tense systems, such as Hebrew, the [past tense can be used to denote future](http://www.ulpan.net/hebrew-past-as-future) events or a condition depending on a future event. It could be that the construction that your friend heard in an English dialect is a loaned construction from a neighboring language without tripartite tense. If so, it would be interesting to know what dialect this is.